# justify-content: space-between doesn't work

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm experiencing a weird render, `justify-content: space-between` doesn't work, meanwhile `justify-content: center` works. Why?

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Add, Remove } from "@material-ui/icons";

const Container = styled.div``;
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  padding: 50px;
  display: flex;
`;
const InfoContainer = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0px 50px;
  text-align: justify;
`;
const AddContainer = styled.div`
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;          //This is my issue
`;
const AmountContainer = styled.div``;
const Amount = styled.span``;
const Button = styled.button`
  cursor: pointer;
`;

const Product = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <Wrapper>
          <InfoContainer>
            <AddContainer>
              <AmountContainer>
                <Remove />
                <Amount>1</Amount>
                <Add />
                <Button>ADD TO CART</Button>
              </AmountContainer>
            </AddContainer>
          </InfoContainer>
        </Wrapper>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Comment: If `AmountContainer` just has one top-level `div`, then there's nothing to space between--it's just one element.

Comment: @Nick i'm trying to space-between the `Button` ADD TO CART and `AmountContainer`. Update: while i'm writing this answer, i recognise my issue, `Button` should be out  `AmountContainer` not wrapped inside it. propblem solved. thanks for the accidental hint.